# General advice on a practice linked_list for C++ classes/templates

Tags: c++, object-oriented, c++11, linked-list, template

**Introduction**

I'm learning C++ (Coming from Haskell, C, and Assembly - and other languages sparsely) and this was my practice with classes and templates. It's a linked list that you can call in this fashion:

```
#include "list.hpp"

int main(void){
   linked_list<char> test;

   char c;

   while(c != '\n') //
      test.prepend(c = fgetc(stdin));

   std::cout << test;

   std::cout << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

**Topic**

I am here to ask if some more experienced coders would point out my mistakes (mainly about classes) so I can break the habits. Thanks for your help!

Here is the source code: (Btw, it isn't optimized on purpose, I was only playing with classes/templates)

(I do notice the inefficient and potentially dangerous tail() call, but considering the trivial nature of the project - I decided to leave it for later, simply make it a deque. I also naively checked it with memcheck. No leaks and no errors in my library, seemingly.)
**[Ideone Link](http://ideone.com/nEohhY)**

```
//Compile with "g++ -std=C++11 -O2 -o list main.cpp list.hpp"

#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class linked_list {
    private:
        int empty = 1;

        struct node {
            T data;
            struct node * next;
        } * head;

        struct node * get_add(int index); 
    public:
        linked_list(){head = new node;};
        linked_list(T data){head = new node; head = data; empty = 0;}
       ~linked_list();

       int size();   
       inline int nsize(){return sizeof(struct node);};
       inline struct node * lhead() {return head;};
       inline struct node * tail() {return get_add(size()-1);};

       int search(T key);

       void prepend(T data);                                     
       void append(T data);
       int insert(T data, int index);
       int del(int index);

       int set(T data, int index);     
       T get(int index);      

       T& operator[](int i);                      
};  

template<typename  T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, linked_list<T> &list); 

//////////////IMPLEMENTATION//////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////

template <typename T>
T& linked_list<T>::operator[](int i){
    return (get_add(i)->data);
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, linked_list<T> &list){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        out << list.get(i);
    return out;
}

template <typename T>
int linked_list<T>::size(){
    int i;
    struct node * tmp = head;

    for(i = 1; tmp->next != NULL; i++)
        tmp = tmp->next;

    return i;
}

template <typename T>
int linked_list<T>::set(T data, int index){
    if(index >= size())
        return -1;

    get_add(index)->data = data;

    return data;
}

template <typename T>
void linked_list<T>::prepend(T data){ 
    if(empty){
        head->data = data;
        empty = 0;
    } else {
        struct node * tmp = new node;
        tmp->data = head->data;
        tmp->next = head->next;

        head->data = data;
        head->next =  tmp;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void linked_list<T>::append(T data){
    if(empty){
        head->data = data;
        empty = 0;
    } else {
        struct node * tmp = new node;

        tmp->data = data;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        tail()->next = tmp;
    }
}

template <typename T>
int linked_list<T>::insert(T data, int index){
    if(index >= size())
        return -1;

    if(empty){
        head->data = data;
        empty = 0;
    } else {
        struct node * tmp = new node;
        struct node * location = get_add(index);
    struct node * prev = get_add(index-1);

    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = location;
        prev->next = tmp;
    }

    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
int linked_list<T>::del(int index){
    if(index >= size())
        return -1;

    struct node * prev = get_add(index-1);
    struct node * tmp = prev->next->next;

    delete prev->next;

    prev->next = tmp;

    return 0;
}


template <typename T>
int linked_list<T>::search(T key){
    int i;
    struct node * tmp = head;

    for(i = 0; key != tmp->data; i++)
        tmp = tmp->next;

    return i;
}

template <typename T>
T linked_list<T>::get(int index){
    if(index >= size())
        return 0;

    int i;
    struct node * tmp = head;

    for(i = 0; tmp->next != NULL && i < index; i++)
        tmp = tmp->next;

    return tmp->data;
}

template <typename T>
struct linked_list<T>::node * linked_list<T>::get_add(int index){
    if(index >= size())
        return 0;

    int i = 0;
    struct node * tmp = head;

    while(i++ < index)
        tmp = tmp->next;

    return tmp;
}

template <typename T>
linked_list<T>::~linked_list(){
    struct node * tmp = head->next;

    for(; head->next != NULL; tmp = head->next){
        head->next = head->next->next;  
        delete tmp;
    }

    delete head;
}
#endif
```

Thanks again.

Comment: In addition to Morwenn's answer, one suggestion is to keep the preprocessor *guards* named consistent with the class (`#ifndef LIST_H`).  I'd recommend `#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H` if you don't use namespaces, just to be consistent with the actual template class name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This won't be as complete an answer as you often see on Code Review, but here are a few pointers to improve your code:

```
template <typename T>
T& linked_list<T>::operator[](int i){
    return (get_add(i)->data);
}
```

First of all, you should tell the programmer that your index will never be a negative one. In order to do so, you could change your `int` parameter to be an `unsigned int` one. Here, since we are talking about sizes, a `size_t` or `std::size_t` parameter would be even better:

```
template <typename T>
T& linked_list<T>::operator[](std::size_t i) {
    return get_add(i)->data;
}
```

C++ differentiates between functions that change the class members and functions that do not. If your function does not change the member variables, it should be const-qualified. Moreover, this qualification is a part of the function's signature. That means that you can have both the const-qualified version of the function in your class and the normal one:

```
template <typename T>
T& linked_list<T>::operator[](std::size_t i) {
    return get_add(i)->data;
}

template <typename T>
const T& linked_list<T>::operator[](std::size_t i) const {
    return get_add(i)->data;
}
```

You can apply my remarks about `const`-qualified functions to every function that should not change the class (e.g. `size` and `search`).

Now, let's talk about this piece of code:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, linked_list<T> &list) { ... }
```

Let's have a look a the function's signature: your parameter is a `linked_list<T>&`. However, you should specify that this output function will not modify your list by adding a `const` before the type:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const linked_list<T> &list) { ... }
```

About `for` loops in C++:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    out << list.get(i);
```

In C++, you can use declaration statements in the first part of the `for`. That means that you don't have to declare your `int i` **before** the loop. You can declare it inside the `for`. And that is what should be done, unless you still need the value of `i` after you leave the loop. You can write it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    out << list.get(i);
```

And since your list can not have negative indices, the `std::size_t` is still welcome:

```
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    out << list.get(i);
```

We will now see this piece of code:

```
int search(T key);
```

While it is valid, you are passing `key` by value, which means that if you pass an instance of a big class (if `T` is a big class), it will be entirely copied before being used. In C++, if we don't need to modify the object passed to a function, it is better to pass it by `const` reference: it will not change the way you use it, but the compiler will use the address of the instance instead of doing a whole copy. To search, you don't need to modify your key, so it is better to pass by `const` reference:

```
int search(const T& key);
```

Comment: Morwenn, this was exactly what I was hoping to get for an answer. Thanks, I'll mark this question as answered if nobody else answers.

Answer (score 8):

A specific note on memory management in particular:

- Don't use raw pointers (`std::unique_ptr` is better -- and then `std::shared_ptr` but only if you're absolutely sure you need to share) -- e.g., you can express the fact that your list owns the resource by using `std::unique_ptr`, while raw pointers leave the ownership semantics unexpressed & undocumented (it's best to be as clear as possible when expressing the intent in the code).
- Don't use raw `new` (right now you're leaking memory if you forget to `delete` after `new` -- and this happens all too often in practice) -- prefer `make_unique` (soon in the standard, for now just Google it) and `std::make_shared` instead.
- Prefer RAII.

See:
- http://speakerdeck.com/lichray/resource-management-the-c-plus-plus-way
- http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1944072
- http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/
- http://www.hackcraft.net/raii/
- http://www.slideshare.net/adankevich/raii-and-scopeguard

Answer (score 5):

- `node` doesn't have a constructor: this means that every instance you create starts out with a garbage `next` pointer, which could cause problems (besides, it's just nasty)

  ```
  struct node {
      T data;
      node *next; // note that node is a type name in C++

      // requires that T is default-constructable
      node() : next(NULL) {}
      // requires that T is copy-constructable
      node(T const &source) : data(source), next(NULL) {}
      // requires C++11 and that T is move-constructable
      node(T &&source) : data(std::move(source)), next(NULL) {}
  };
  ```
- you *always* `new` and then `delete` your head node, so the indirection doesn't buy you any flexibility (ie, it can never legally be NULL). So, just make it a regular member:

  ```
  node head; // this is a sentinel-style list head
  ```

  and now you never need to `new` or `delete` it. Now it has a default constructor too, you don't need to mention it in your constructors at all
- `empty` should be type `bool`, if it can only be `true` or `false`. However, we can do without it entirely, since the identity `empty == (head.next == NULL)` is required to be true. Let's just add

  ```
  bool empty() const { return head.next == NULL; }
  ```

  and use `empty()` instead of `empty` everywhere.
- conversely, `size()` is really expensive, so we can replace the member we just saved with `int size;` and use that instead of the function call

Answer (score 3):

Here's a few issues that I noticed:

1. Initialising private member `empty` is not allowed
2. I would find it more natural to have the `head` pointer as just a `struct node *` instead of being a node itself.  Then if `head` is NULL, the list is empty and the `empty` variable is not necessary.
3. I would prefer `get_address`, or at least `get_addr` to `get_add`
4. 2nd constructor should say `head->data = data;`
5. `nsize` better as `sizeof(node)`
6. `tail` fails if list is empty
7. do the method names match those of standartd containers?
8. operator[] fails if list is empty
9. use braces even on single-line blocks (after if, for, etc)
10. declare loop-variabless within loops where possible
11. `size` returns 1 even for an empty list
12. `set` returns `int` rather than `T`
13. in `prepend` it would be slightly easier to replace the `head` pointer with `tmp`
14. `insert` fails if index is zero.  It would also be more logical just to search for `index-1` (if index!=0) instead of searching for both `index-1` **and** `index`
15. `del` fails if index is zero.
16. `insert` and `del` might be better returning `bool` rather than 0/-1
17. `search` should handle an empty list separately
18. `get` could be written using `get_add`

Comment: 1. is no longer true for C++11. This has been introduced as "non-static data member initializers".