# 'Genetic algorithm' implementation for constructing a battle mech

Tags: c++

This is a simple but complete console application where I experiment with genetic algorithm to try to figure out the best way to construct a battle mech that would win in a simple turn-based combat.

I welcome your criticism and pointers about what I could improve in the code above: architecture-wise, technique-wise, presentation-wise, and whatever else catches your interest. To provide at least a sample code as per the local rules, this is the method to make two mechs meet in combat:

```
// Match::match()
// ==============
// A static method that can be used to execute a match between the two provided mechs.
// Return value: 0 = draw, 1 = mech #1 wins, 2 = mech #2 wins.

int Match::match (Mech& m1, Mech& m2) {

    m1.resetCombatValues();
    m2.resetCombatValues();

    int turn = 0;
    static const int turnLimit = 25;

    // Each turn:
    while (turn < turnLimit) {

        m1.actCombatTurn (m2);
        m2.actCombatTurn (m1);

        bool mech1Alive = m1.isAlive();
        bool mech2Alive = m2.isAlive();

        if (!mech1Alive && !mech2Alive) return 0;

        if (!mech1Alive) return 2;
        if (!mech2Alive) return 1;

        turn++;

    }

    // Turn limit reached. 
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Instead of coded return values, I'd consider using an enumeration for clarity: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

// A good rule of thumb is that if you have to document a special meaning of (implicit) enumerators, like "0 = draw, 1 = mech #1 wins, 2 = mech #2 wins", then it's probably better to use an explicit enumeration.

Comment: I would also suggest making this a namespace non-member function instead of a static member function: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1435105/859774

Comment: Further, unless you're supporting negative turns count `turnLimit` or want `turn` to go backward (would that even make sense in your context? BTW, `turn++` looks awkward, change it to `++turn`), I would use `size_t` instead of `int` for `turn` and `turnLimit`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t

Comment: I think I also wouldn't use `mech1Alive` or `mech2Alive` but rather their opposites (e.g., `mech1Dead` or `mech2Dead`) -- note that you're always negating them in your `if` statements, so it would improve code clarity to do so straight away.

Comment: You do realize that the rules are there for a reason, right?

Comment: @Matt Thanks a lot! Good points, I especially like the one with the explicit enumeration to clear up what is the return value, that does make it all easier to read. I edited the online version.

Comment: @MartinZiegler Sure! I've just looked at the online version, BTW. Your next step should be to remove _all_ uses of `new` and _all_ of the resource-owning raw pointers: preferably change them to (stack-allocated) automatic variables, then _only_ for the ones for which you can't do that (if any, don't just assume that, but _carefully_ verify that free-store/heap dynamic allocation is _absolutely_ required!) use `std::unique_ptr`, and finally, as a last resort, use `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a summary of my comments in the answer format:

- Instead of coded return values, I'd consider using an enumeration for clarity: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum
  // A good rule of thumb is that if you have to document a special meaning of (implicit) enumerators, like "`0 = draw, 1 = mech #1 wins, 2 = mech #2 wins`", then it's probably better to use an explicit enumeration.
- I would also suggest using a namespace non-member function instead of a static member function whenever possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1435105/859774
- Further, unless you're supporting negative turns count `turnLimit` or want turn to go backward (would that even make sense in your context? BTW, `turn++` looks awkward, change it to `++turn`), I would use `size_t` instead of `int` for `turn` and `turnLimit`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t
  // NOTE: in fact, the cases where `int` is the right type to choose are *significantly* rarer than most beginning developers seem to assume -- as a good rule of thumb, whenever you think you should use an `int`, you should always stop and think whether it's actually a good idea -- e.g., are you *sure* you really want negative values?
- I also wouldn't use `mech1Alive` or `mech2Alive` but rather their opposites (e.g., `mech1Dead` or `mech2Dead`) -- note that you're always negating them in your `if` statements, so it would improve code clarity to do so straight away, at the outset.
- I've just looked at the online version, BTW. Your next step should be to remove *all* uses of `new` (and, consequently, *all* manual invocations of `delete`) and *all* of the resource-owning raw pointers: preferably change them to (stack-allocated) automatic variables (using references, preferably to `const`, when avoiding copies is necessary), then *only* for the ones for which you can't possibly do that (if there are any, don't just assume this, but *carefully* verify that free-store/heap dynamic allocation is in fact *absolutely* required!) use `std::unique_ptr`, and finally, as a last resort, use `std::shared_ptr` (and, as a last resort after this last resort ;], in the *extremely rare* case you have need to break a cycle, consider `std::weak_ptr`).
  See: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/25721/24670

Comment: Thanks a lot – I've reworked the structure so that I do not allocate 'on my own' almost anywhere now. I still allocate new Mechs dynamically and only store the pointer within the population vector, because it is quite a heavy structure to move around, and I do move it around quite a lot. I store those as `unique_ptr`'s in the Population that created them, so AFAIU that should be OK.