# 'Evolutionary AI' implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, ai

For the code sample that I am asked to submit with most of my job applications (usually Gameplay Programmer), I created this console application in which I attempt to figure out what is the best loadout for a mech to win a match within the simple turn-based combat system that I came up with. Since I will submit this as a code sample, it is important to me that it works and looks the best, and I would really appreciate all the input that you could give me.

I would like to mention that I already posted [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26600/how-can-i-improve-this-c-genetic-algorithm-implementation) sometime last summer, but since then I reworked it considerably (mostly because I studied up on C++11), so I hope it's OK to resubmit.

What I'm interested in is really everything that comes to your mind when you see this — about the design, implementation, presentation, naming,  or really anything that you think is important.

In particular, am I really taking advantage of all the C+11 concepts that I can, and am I using them in a correct manner?

The code as well as the rules are available online: http://www.mz1net.com/code-sample

(UPDATE: I've updated the online version with the edits that I made based on Jamal's response.)

This is Main.cpp - please see the 'MechArena.cpp' and 'MechArena.h' online:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>

#include "MechArena.h"

// ======================================================================================

void init() 
{
    srand((int)time(0));

    std::cout << "=== MECH ARENA ============================" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "===========================================" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

// ======================================================================================

int promptPopulationSize() 
{
    std::cout << "Enter the population size (10K recommended): ";

    // Loop until we have a valid result:
    while (true) 
    {
        std::string input;
        getline(std::cin, input);

        int size; 
        std::stringstream parser (input);
        if (parser >> size) 
        {
            if (size % 2 > 0) 
            {
                std::cout << "Population size was rounded up to an even number: " << size+1 << std::endl;
                size++;
            }

            std::cout << std::endl;
            return size;
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter a valid number: ";
        }
    }
}

// ======================================================================================

void run() 
{
    init();
    int populationSize = promptPopulationSize();

    std::cout << "Random population seed... " << std::endl;

    Population population (populationSize);
    std::cout << "Population created." << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // This is the main application loop.
    // Repeatedly, we prompt the user to choose a command, and than we act on his or her decision.
    // We break the loop when the user chooses the 'exit' command.
    while (true) 
    {
        std::cout << "Instructions:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "-------------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[Q/W/E/R]: Run 50/25/5/1 evolution steps." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[A/S/D]:   Display the 10/5/1 best loadouts in the current population." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[X]:       Exit." << std::endl;

        char command = _getch();
        std::cout << std::endl;

    // NEXT GENERATION

        int evolutionSteps = 0;
        if (command == 'q') evolutionSteps = 50;
        if (command == 'w') evolutionSteps = 25;
        if (command == 'e') evolutionSteps = 5;
        if (command == 'r') evolutionSteps = 1;

        // Run the evolution steps:
        for (int m = 0; m < evolutionSteps; m++) 
        {
            std::cout << "Generation " << m+1 << "/" << evolutionSteps << ": ";
            population.createNextGeneration();

            std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;
        }

    // DISPLAY WINNERS

        size_t displayWinners = 0;
        if (command == 'a') displayWinners = 10;
        if (command == 's') displayWinners = 5;
        if (command == 'd') displayWinners = 1;

        if (displayWinners > 0) 
        {
            // Make sure that we were not asked to display more 
            // mechs than how many there are in the entire population.
            size_t populationSize = population.getSize();
            if (displayWinners > populationSize) 
            {
                std::cout << "There are not that many mechs in the entire population - only " << populationSize << " will be shown.";
                std::cout << std::endl;

                displayWinners = populationSize;
            }

            std::cout << "TOP " << displayWinners << ((displayWinners > 1)? " MECHS" : " MECH") << " IN THE POPULATION: " << std::endl;
            std::cout << "--------------------------------------" << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl;

            for (size_t m = 0; m < displayWinners; m++) 
            {
                // Retrieve the mech to show.
                const Mech& mech = population.getMech(m);

                // Print out the mech's position and its score in the last match round.
                std::cout << "TOP #" << m+1 << " (Last score: " << mech.getScore() << ")" << std::endl;

                // Print out the mech's component setup.
                std::cout << mech;
            }
        }

    // EXIT

        // Break the main application loop.
        if (command == 'x') 
            break;

    // CLEAR

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

// ======================================================================================

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try 
    {
        run();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) 
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[!] RUNTIME EXCEPTION ==============================" << std::endl;
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Press any key to exit." << std::endl;
        std::cin.ignore();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`#include`s:**

- <s>`<time.h>` is a C library; use `<ctime>` instead.</s>
- Consider omitting `<conio.h>` as there could be some portability issues.  It's also not widely used in C++, especially since you have `<iostream>`.
- <s>Add `<cstdlib>` for `std::srand()`/`std::rand()`.</s>
- Add `<exception>` for `std::exception`.

**Everything else:**

- <s>*Only call `std::srand()` once in an application, preferably in `main()`*.  Even if `init()` will be called only once, keeping it in `main()` will help with maintainability.</s>

  In addition, prefer to `static cast` cast to an `unsigned int` and, especially in C++11, **use `nullptr`** instead of `NULL` or `0` for this use.

  So, you'll have this:

  ```
  std::srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(nullptr)));
  ```

  As you're not really using any random number generation here (no calls to `std::rand()`), just omit the relevant headers and the call to `std::srand()`.

  **You should refrain from using `rand` altogether in C++11 as it is [considered harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).  Instead, utilize C++11's [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) library.**

  You also no longer need `<ctime>` and should use C++11's [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).  From this library, you can obtain a seed for a PRNG with this:

  ```
  auto chrono_seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
  ```
- `init()` is needless as it's primarily outputting hard-coded text, which shouldn't be any function's primary task.  Just move all the output to `main()` and remove the function.

  Also, use `"\n"` for that output instead of `std::endl`.  You don't need all that flushing there.

  ```
  std::cout << "=== MECH ARENA ============================\n";
  std::cout << "===========================================\n\n";
  ```
- Be careful with catching exceptions here.  Make sure you know which exception you're expecting to catch while knowing how to handle it.  It appears you're trying to catch a runtime error, so you should catch an [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) instead.
- Anything modular 2 is either 0 or 1, so just compare inequality to 0 (or equality to 1) if you're determining if `size` is an odd number:

  ```
  if (size % 2 != 0)
  ```

  ```
  if (size % 2 == 1)
  ```

  Another ([possibly faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/160942/1950231)) alternative is to use the bitwise AND operator:

  ```
  if ((size & 1) == 0)
  ```

Comment: Good points, thanks a lot. I'll update the online version in a minute: it now uses <ctime>, includes <exception> (it was included via <iostream>), has all the `std::endl` replaced with '\n', has the entire `init()` moved into `main()`, supplies `nullptr` as the parameter to `std::srand`, and I rewrote the `size % 2` line. Fair point with the `<conio.h>`, but I think I'll probably keep it, because being able to read the control character from the console without Enter makes the application so much easier to use, and I think that pretty much all the studios that will receive this are on Windows.

Comment: @electroLux: I'm making some additional corrections now.

Comment: If you're talking about pausing the console, there are alternatives that do not use `<conio.h>`.

Comment: What I want is for the user not to have to press Enter when I prompt him to press a key to choose an an action to take. When I show something like "[W]: Evolve / [X]: Show", I want the to react immediately to the 'W' key press, and not having to wait for  user to press 'W' and then Enter. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7461203/1549314) makes me think that I need to use `<conio.h>` in order to do that.

Comment: @electroLux: That's fine, then.  I just wanted to at least make you aware of the portability.

Comment: Both `srand` and `rand` are ugly and [harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) as well. We have got C++11. Leave that C-style stuff and move on.

Comment: @Jamal I'd add `<chrono>` which will generate the seed.

Comment: @no1: As a replacement of `<ctime>`?

Comment: @Jamal Yes. You might want:
`auto chrono_seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();`  
 rather than
`auto time_seed = time(nullptr);`  
Also the first one generates bigger seeds than the second one.

Comment: @no1: Okay.  Is this just for `srand` or any of the `<random>` functions?  C++11 already has `std::random_device`.  By the way, I'm asking all of this because I've never used `<chrono>` before.

Comment: @Jamal You're welcome. If you need a PRNG such as `mt19937`/`mt19937_64`, it needs a seed.
`std::random_device` doesn't, instead. (it isn't a PRNG)    
  
STL talks about that as well in his talk.

Comment: @no1: I see.  I'll mention the first seed.

Comment: I'd like to point out that there's a much faster way to determine whether a number is odd:
`if (number & 1) // odd else //even`

Answer (score 10):

There's something which worries me about using this as a sample for a job application: which is that it contains no `virtual` methods and no subclasses.

No matter how clearly-written your code may be, it doesn't demonstrate an understanding of inheritance: which (I don't know) might be an important criterion in a job application.

If this is valid criticism, perhaps change the game design so as to use inheritance in a natural way.

One (advanced) way to do this might be to have the type of weapon have a different effect depending on the type of armour (as in a game or "rock, paper, sissors", the effect of the weapon varies depending on the target). I'm thinking of this as an example, because a "implementing a video game" is the canonical example used to teach an 'advanced' technique called [double-dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch). Working that implementation (if game-rule have a natural need for that implementation technique) into your sample might impress someone reviewing resumes/samples.

People might also like to see a knowledge of (i.e. appropriate use of some) common [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern).

My apologies for this advice: it's based on a cynical guess at the type of code which some interviewers may be looking for.

Again based on experience with interview questions, they might also like to know:

- How do/did you test this?
- Have you thought about how to extend/maintain it various ways? I mean, add new types of feature: a GUI; playing it over the network; persisting (saving and restoring) game-state; making it a 0-player, 1-player, 2-player, or many-player game; etc.

Comment: My answer is based on a review of the code posted at http://www.mz1net.com/code-sample (not of the code quoted above which Jamal was already inspecting).

Comment: If relevant to this answer at all, consider including some snippets from that linked code in case the link dies.

Comment: Good point. Fortunately, I am asked to deliver several code samples, so besides the two that I already have, I'll probably prepare another one where I will use some polymorphism. I have an idea about a simple Visitor example, so that would also address the design patterns aspect.

Comment: @electroLux Some knowledge of multi-threading / thread-safety is another popular topic, at least in the C++ jobs I apply for.

Comment: @ChrisW For sure. I think that the issue with the code samples is that I would obviously like them to represent all that I can do, but they are supposed to be quite short, so ultimately I will inevitably only demonstrate only a subset of the skills that the studios would me like me to have.