# Follow-up: C++ 'evolutionary AI' implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, ai

Based on the advice provided in [my previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39097/how-can-i-improve-this-c-evolutionary-ai-implementation), I would like to post the other source file that actually implements all the combat mechanics and also the actual evolution process.

As with the previous question, I am interested in all kinds of feedback — regarding design, implementation, algorithms, presentation, style, cleanliness, correct C++11 usage, or anything that you think that could make this work better as an impressive code sample submitted to support a job application.

The entire code as well as the rules can be seen at http://www.mz1net.com/code-sample — that is also where the 'MechArena.h' that declares the classes and describes them a little better is available.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <exception>

#include "MechArena.h"

// COMPONENT SET ========================================================================
// ======================================================================================

// The no-param constructor initialises the component list with random components.
template<typename T>
Components<T>::Components (size_t size) 
{
    for (size_t m = 0; m < size; m++) 
    {
        T component = Components<T>::randomComponent();
        this->components.push_back(component);
    }
}

// ======================================================================================

// The 'crossover' constructor creates a new Components instance that randomly mixes the 
// components used by the two provided parents component sets. Some components will also 
// be randomly switched to a random component due to mutation.
template<typename T>
Components<T>::Components (const Components<T>& c1, const Components<T>& c2) 
{
    size_t c1Size = c1.components.size();
    size_t c2Size = c2.components.size();
    if (c1Size != c2Size) 
    {
        throw std::exception("Crossover is impossible between component sets that do not have the same size.");
    }

    // For each component in the set, decide randomly which parent's component the new 
    // component set will inherit. For optimisation, we request one random number and use 
    // its bits to decide on the respective component slots.
    int r = rand();
    for (size_t m = 0; m < c1Size; m++)
    {
        int mask = 1 << m;
        this->components.push_back( (r & mask) ? c1.components.at(m) : c2.components.at(m) );
    }

    // Mutation: 
    for (T& component : this->components)
    {
        if (rand()%1000 <= 50)
        {
            component = Components::randomComponent();
        }
    }
}

// ======================================================================================

template<typename T>
const std::vector<T>& Components<T>::getList() const 
{
    return this->components;
}

// ======================================================================================

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Components<T>& c) 
{
    for (T component : c.getList())
    {
        os << componentName(component) << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}

// ======================================================================================

// For each component type (armor/weapon/reactor/aux), we specialise the 
// 'randomComponent' method so that it works with the correct enumeration:
ArmorComponent Components<ArmorComponent>::randomComponent() 
{    
    int r = rand() % COMP_ARMOR_LAST;
    return static_cast<ArmorComponent>(r);
}

// ======================================================================================

WeaponComponent Components<WeaponComponent>::randomComponent() 
{    
    int r = rand() % COMP_WEAPON_LAST;
    return static_cast<WeaponComponent>(r);
}

// ======================================================================================

ReactorComponent Components<ReactorComponent>::randomComponent() 
{    
    int r = rand() % COMP_REACTOR_LAST;
    return static_cast<ReactorComponent>(r);
}

// ======================================================================================

AuxComponent Components<AuxComponent>::randomComponent() 
{    
    int r = rand() % COMP_AUX_LAST;
    return static_cast<AuxComponent>(r);
}

// WEAPON ===============================================================================
// ======================================================================================

Weapon::Weapon (Mech& owner, WeaponComponent component) : 
    owner(owner),
    component(component)
{
    switch (component) 
    {
    case COMP_WEAPON_LASER_HEAVY:
        this->hits = 30;
        this->cooldown = 5;
        this->hitType = HT_PULSE;
        break;

    case COMP_WEAPON_LASER_FAST:
        this->hits = 10;
        this->cooldown = 2;
        this->hitType = HT_PULSE;
        break;

    case COMP_WEAPON_MISSILE_LAUNCHER:
        this->hits = 50;
        this->cooldown = 4;
        this->hitType = HT_BLAST;
        break;

    default:
        throw std::exception("Cannot setup a Weapon - there are no data related to the provided component.");
    }

    this->readyIn = this->cooldown;
    this->calibration = false;
}

// ======================================================================================

// Applies a reactor component to the weapon, so that the weapon can alter 
// its values (cooldown, hit amount, etc.) based on the particular component.
void Weapon::applyReactorComponent (ReactorComponent component) 
{
    // Heavy Laser: Reduce cooldown with Heat Sink.
    if (this->component == COMP_WEAPON_LASER_HEAVY && component == COMP_REACTOR_HEAT_SINK) 
    {
        this->cooldown--;
    }

    // Missile Launcher: Reduce cooldown with Advanced Lock-On System.
    if (this->component == COMP_WEAPON_MISSILE_LAUNCHER && component == COMP_REACTOR_LOCK_ON) 
    {
        this->cooldown--;
    }

    // Fast Laser: Increase hit amount with Predictive Scanners.
    if (this->component == COMP_WEAPON_LASER_FAST && component == COMP_REACTOR_SCANNERS) 
    {
        this->hits = int (this->hits * 1.5);
    }
}

// ======================================================================================

// Makes the weapon act in the mech's combat turn. Reduces the weapon's cooldown, and in 
// case that this makes the weapon able to attack this turn, it attacks the provided opponent.
void Weapon::act (Mech& opponent) 
{   
    this->readyIn--;
    if (this->readyIn > 0) return;

    // For missile-based weapons, check that the mech can spend a missile:
    if (!this->requiresMissile() || this->owner.spendMissile()) 
    {
        opponent.receiveHit(this->hitType, this->hits, this->calibration);
        this->readyIn = this->cooldown;
    }
}

// ======================================================================================

bool Weapon::requiresMissile() 
{
    return (this->component == COMP_WEAPON_MISSILE_LAUNCHER);
}

// ======================================================================================

void Weapon::reset() {

    this->readyIn = this->cooldown;

}

// MECH =================================================================================
// ======================================================================================

// The no-param constructor creates a new mech with a random component setup.
Mech::Mech() : 
    armorComponents(3), 
    weaponComponents(4), 
    reactorComponents(3), 
    auxComponents(2) 
{       
    this->initID();
    this->initCombatValues();
}

// ======================================================================================

// The crossover constructor creates a new crossover mech that is based on the two provided 
// parents. The new mech randomly mixes components of its parents, and some components can 
// also be randomly switched to another due to mutation.
Mech::Mech (const Mech& m1, const Mech& m2) : 
    armorComponents   (m1.armorComponents,   m2.armorComponents),
    weaponComponents  (m1.weaponComponents,  m2.weaponComponents),
    reactorComponents (m1.reactorComponents, m2.reactorComponents), 
    auxComponents     (m1.auxComponents,     m2.auxComponents) 
{
    this->initID();
    this->initCombatValues();
}

// ======================================================================================

// Provides the mech with a unique ID. 
// This needs to be called by all the constructors.
void Mech::initID() 
{
    static int ID = 0;
    this->ID = ++ID;
}

// ======================================================================================

// Calculates all the mech's combat values based on its component setup.
// This needs to be called by all the constructors.
void Mech::initCombatValues() 
{
    this->maxArmor = 100;
    this->armorAutoRepair = 0;
    this->pulseAbsorb = 0;
    this->interceptor = false;
    this->repairBots = false;
    this->maxMissiles = 0;
    this->maxCountermeasures = 0;
    this->maxNanobots = 0;
    this->score = 0;

    // Armor:
    for (ArmorComponent component : this->armorComponents.getList())
    {
        switch (component) 
        {
        case COMP_ARMOR_BONUS:
            this->maxArmor += 35;
            break;

        case COMP_ARMOR_REPAIR_AUTO:
            this->armorAutoRepair += 5;
            break;

        case COMP_ARMOR_REPAIR_BOTS:
            this->repairBots = true;
            this->nanobots += 1;
            break;

        case COMP_ARMOR_MISSILE_INTERCEPTOR:
            this->interceptor = true;
            this->countermeasures += 1;
            break;

        case COMP_ARMOR_LASER_ABSORB:
            this->pulseAbsorb += 2;
            break;

        default:
            throw std::exception("Cannot setup the mech with the provided armor component.");
        }
    }

    // Weapons:
    for (WeaponComponent component : this->weaponComponents.getList())
    {
        this->weapons.push_back( Weapon(*this, component) );
    }

    // Reactor:
    for (ReactorComponent component : this->reactorComponents.getList())
    {
        // Let all the weapons update their internal values based on the reactor component:
        for (std::vector<Weapon>::iterator weaponIt = this->weapons.begin(); weaponIt != this->weapons.end(); weaponIt++) 
        {
            weaponIt->applyReactorComponent(component);
        }
    }

    // Auxiliary:
    for (AuxComponent component : this->auxComponents.getList())
    {
        switch (component) 
        {
        case COMP_AUX_MISSILES:
            this->maxMissiles += 4;
            break;

        case COMP_AUX_COUNTERMEASURES:
            this->maxCountermeasures += 2;
            break;

        case COMP_AUX_NANOBOTS:
            this->maxNanobots += 3;
            break;

        default:
            throw std::exception("Cannot setup the mech with the provided auxiliary component.");
        }
    }
}

// ======================================================================================

// Executes a match between the two provided mechs and returns the match result. 
// This is a static method that expects both the match participants as parameters. 
MatchResult Mech::match (Mech& m1, Mech& m2) 
{
    m1.resetCombatValues();
    m2.resetCombatValues();

    int turn = 0;
    static const int turnLimit = 25;

    // Each turn:
    while (turn < turnLimit) 
    {
        m1.actCombatTurn(m2);
        m2.actCombatTurn(m1);

        bool mech1Dead = !m1.isAlive();
        bool mech2Dead = !m2.isAlive();

        if (mech1Dead && mech2Dead) return MATCH_RESULT_DRAW;

        if (mech1Dead) return MATCH_RESULT_MECH_2_WINS;
        if (mech2Dead) return MATCH_RESULT_MECH_1_WINS;

        turn++;
    }

    return MATCH_RESULT_DRAW;
}

// ======================================================================================

// Allows the mech to take all the actions that it can take in its combat turn: 
// use or cool down its weapons, auto-repair, use nanobots to repair, etc.
void Mech::actCombatTurn (Mech& opponent) 
{
    this->autoRepair();
    this->botRepair();
    this->attack(opponent);
}

// ======================================================================================

// Executes the mech's auto-repairs.
void Mech::autoRepair() 
{
    this->armor = std::min(this->armor + this->armorAutoRepair, this->maxArmor);
}

// ======================================================================================

// Makes the mech use its nanobot repair module in its combat turn, when appropriate.
void Mech::botRepair() 
{
    // Check that the mech has the repair 
    // module and also a nanobot to spare.
    if (!this->repairBots) return;
    if (this->nanobots <= 0) return;

    // Do not repair unless needed.
    const int nanobotRepairAmount = 20;
    if (this->armor > this->maxArmor - nanobotRepairAmount) return;

    // Repair and spend the nanobot.
    this->armor += nanobotRepairAmount;
    this->nanobots--;
}

// ======================================================================================

// Makes the mech act with all its weapons in its combat turn.
void Mech::attack (Mech& opponent) 
{
    for (Weapon& weapon : this->weapons)
    {
        weapon.act(opponent);
    }
}

// ======================================================================================

// Makes the mech receive a combat hit. This reduces the mech's armor.
// The mech is allowed to use all its protection mechanisms (countermeasures, laser absorbs).
// For calibrated hits, the hit destroys a missile, a countermeasure, or a nanobot.
void Mech::receiveHit (HitType hitType, int hits, bool calibration) 
{
    // Pulse hits: Reduce the hit amount by our 'laser absorb' value.
    if (hitType == HT_PULSE) 
    {
        this->armor -= (hits - this->pulseAbsorb);
    }

    // Blast hits: Counter them with a countermeasure, if available.
    if (hitType == HT_BLAST) 
    {
        if (this->interceptor && this->countermeasures > 0) 
        {
            this->countermeasures--;
        }
        else  
        {
            this->armor -= hits;
        }
    }

    // For calibrated hits, destroy a 
    // missile/countermeasure/nanobot.
    if (calibration) 
    {
        if (this->missiles > 0) 
        {
            this->missiles--;
        } 
        else if (this->countermeasures > 0) 
        {
            this->countermeasures--;
        }
        else if (this->nanobots > 0) 
        {
            this->nanobots--;
        }
    }
}

// ======================================================================================

bool Mech::isAlive() const 
{
    return (this->armor > 0);
}

// ======================================================================================

// Makes the mech spend a missile. Returns 'true' when the mech had a missile to spare. 
// Returns 'false' when the mech was out of missiles.
bool Mech::spendMissile() 
{
    if (this->missiles > 0) 
    {
        this->missiles--;
        return true;
    }   
    return false;
}

// ======================================================================================

// Restores all the mech's combat status values (armor, weapon cooldowns, missiles, etc.) 
// to their initial values, so that it can start a new combat match. 
void Mech::resetCombatValues() 
{
    this->armor = this->maxArmor;
    this->missiles = this->maxMissiles;
    this->countermeasures = this->maxCountermeasures;
    this->nanobots = this->maxNanobots;

    for (Weapon& weapon : this->weapons)
    {
        weapon.reset();
    }
}

// ======================================================================================

void Mech::addScore (int point) 
{
    this->score += point;
}

// ======================================================================================

void Mech::resetScore() 
{
    this->score = 0;
}

// ======================================================================================

int Mech::getScore() const 
{
    return this->score;
}

// ======================================================================================

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Mech& m) 
{   
    os << "MECH #" << m.ID << " SPECIFICATIONS:\n";
    os << "=========================\n";

    os << " [ARMOR]:\n";
    os << m.armorComponents << '\n';

    os << " [WEAPON]:\n";
    os << m.weaponComponents << '\n';

    os << " [REACTOR]:\n";
    os << m.reactorComponents << '\n';

    os << " [AUX]:\n" ;
    os << m.auxComponents << '\n';

    return os;
}

// POPULATION ===========================================================================
// ======================================================================================

Population::Population (size_t size) 
    : size(size) 
{
    // The population size has to be an even number, so that we will later 
    // be able to pair up all the mechs with an opponent in a combat round.
    if (size % 2 > 0) {
        throw std::exception("The population size has to be an even number.");
    }

    // Fill the population with random mechs. 
    this->mechs.reserve(size);
    for (size_t m = 0; m < size; m++) 
    {
        this->mechs.push_back( std::unique_ptr<Mech> ( new Mech() ) );
    }

    this->sorted = true;
}

// ======================================================================================

void Population::createNextGeneration() 
{
    this->runMatches();
    this->prune();
    this->procreate();  
}

// ======================================================================================

// Resets the all the mechs' scores and executes several match rounds.
void Population::runMatches() 
{
    for (auto& mech : this->mechs)
    {
        mech->resetScore();
    }

    const static int rounds = 40;
    for (int m = 0; m < rounds; m++) 
    {
        this->runMatchRound();
    }
}

// ======================================================================================

// Randomly pairs all the mechs up with an opponent and makes the pairs execute a match.
void Population::runMatchRound() 
{
    // Create an index queue that will contain indices [0 .. size] into the mech vector in 
    // a randomised order, then use this queue to pair up the mechs into their matches.

    std::vector<size_t> queue;
    for (size_t m = 0; m < this->mechs.size(); m++) 
    {
        queue.push_back(m);
    }

    std::random_shuffle(queue.begin(), queue.end());

    while (!queue.empty()) 
    {
        size_t index1 = *queue.rbegin(); queue.pop_back();
        size_t index2 = *queue.rbegin(); queue.pop_back();

        Mech& mech1 = *this->mechs[index1];
        Mech& mech2 = *this->mechs[index2];

        // Execute the match:
        MatchResult matchResult = Mech::match(mech1, mech2);
        switch (matchResult) 
        {
        case MATCH_RESULT_MECH_1_WINS:
            mech1.addScore(5);
            break;

        case MATCH_RESULT_MECH_2_WINS:
            mech2.addScore(5);
            break;

        case MATCH_RESULT_DRAW:
            mech1.addScore(1);
            mech2.addScore(1);
            break;
        }    
    }

    this->sorted = false;
}

// ======================================================================================

// Calculates a score threshold based on the arithmetic mean between all the 
// scores the population, and releases all the mechs that scored below this limit.
void Population::prune() 
{
    int scoreTotal = 0;
    for (auto& mech : this->mechs)  {
        scoreTotal += mech->getScore();
    }

    int scoreThreshold = scoreTotal / this->mechs.size();

    // For all the mechs below the score threshold, release the mech and reset its pointer in the 
    // population to indicate that it needs to be replaced with a new mech in the procreation step.
    for (auto& mech : this->mechs)
    {
        if (mech->getScore() < scoreThreshold) 
        {
            mech.reset();
        }
    }
}

// ======================================================================================

// Replaces all the mechs that were released in the 'prune' step with new mechs. Each survivor's 
// score is used as the relative chance that it will be selected as a parent to a new mech.
void Population::procreate() 
{
    // Build up the parent pool – a container that we will use to randomly select 
    // parents. The parents are represented by their indices into the mech list.
    WeightedSet<size_t> parents;
    for (size_t index = 0; index < this->mechs.size(); index++)
    {
        if (this->mechs[index] != nullptr)
        {
            parents.insert(index, this->mechs[index]->getScore());
        }
    }

    // For each mech that was released:
    for (auto& mech : this->mechs) 
    {
        if (mech != nullptr) continue;

        Mech& parent1 = *this->mechs[ parents.random() ];
        Mech& parent2 = *this->mechs[ parents.random() ];

        mech = std::unique_ptr<Mech> ( new Mech (parent1, parent2) );
    }
}

// ======================================================================================

// Returns the mech with the N-th best score.
const Mech& Population::getMech (size_t index) 
{
    if (index >= this->mechs.size()) 
    {
        throw std::exception("The provided mech index is out of bounds.");
    }

    this->sort();
    return *this->mechs.at(index);
}

// ======================================================================================

// Sorts the mechs, winners to losers.
void Population::sort() 
{
    if (this->sorted) return;

    std::sort(this->mechs.begin(), this->mechs.end(), 
        [](const std::unique_ptr<Mech>& m1, const std::unique_ptr<Mech>& m2) 
        { 
            return m1->getScore() > m2->getScore(); 
        }
        );

    this->sorted = true;
}

// ======================================================================================

size_t Population::getSize() const 
{
    return this->size;
}

// WEIGHTED SET =========================================================================
// ======================================================================================

template<typename T>
void WeightedSet<T>::insert (T val, int w) 
{
    this->values[ this->maxValue() + w ] = val;
}

// ======================================================================================

// Returns a random element from the set, with the elements' weights 
// serving as relative probabilities that the element will be selected.
template<typename T>
T WeightedSet<T>::random() 
{
    if (this->values.empty()) 
    {
        throw std::exception("An empty set cannot be queried for a random value");
    }

    // Generate a random number and use the cumulative weights map to 
    // locate the first element with its cumulative weight greater than the number.
    int r = rand() % this->maxValue();
    std::map<int, T>::iterator it = this->values.upper_bound(r);
    if (it == this->values.end()) 
    {
        throw std::exception("WeightedSet integrity failure.");
    }

    return it->second;
}

// ======================================================================================

template<typename T>
int WeightedSet<T>::maxValue() const 
{
    return (this->values.empty()) ? 0 : this->values.crbegin()->first;
}

// COMPONENT NAMES ======================================================================
// ======================================================================================

// Functions that provides translations between the Armor/Weapon/Reactor/AuxComponent 
// enumeration values and their human-readable component names.
template<>
std::string componentName (ArmorComponent ac) 
{
    switch (ac) 
    {
    case COMP_ARMOR_BONUS: return "Thermo-Carbon-60 Armor Plates"; 
    case COMP_ARMOR_REPAIR_AUTO: return "Auto-Replicative Fibres";
    case COMP_ARMOR_REPAIR_BOTS: return "Nanobot Repair Module"; 
    case COMP_ARMOR_MISSILE_INTERCEPTOR: return "AIMS: Anti-Missile System";
    case COMP_ARMOR_LASER_ABSORB: return "Inverse EM Field";
    default: 
        throw std::exception("The provided ArmorComponent does not have a textual description.");
    }
}

// ======================================================================================

template<>
std::string componentName (WeaponComponent wc) 
{
    switch (wc) 
    {
    case COMP_WEAPON_LASER_FAST: return "Black Adder: Fast Laser"; 
    case COMP_WEAPON_LASER_HEAVY: return "Obliterator: Heavy Laser";
    case COMP_WEAPON_MISSILE_LAUNCHER: return "Trebuchet: Missile Launcher"; 
    default: 
        throw std::exception("The provided WeaponComponent does not have a textual description.");
    }
}

// ======================================================================================

template<>
std::string componentName (ReactorComponent rc) 
{
    switch (rc) 
    {
    case COMP_REACTOR_HEAT_SINK: return "White Noise Heat Sink"; 
    case COMP_REACTOR_LOCK_ON: return "Advanced Missile Lock-on System";
    case COMP_REACTOR_SCANNERS: return "Predictive Scanners"; 
    case COMP_REACTOR_CALIBRATION: return "Explosive Laser Calibration Module";
    default: 
        throw std::exception("The provided ReactorComponent does not have a textual description.");
    }
}

// ======================================================================================

template<>
std::string componentName (AuxComponent ac) 
{
    switch (ac) {

    case COMP_AUX_MISSILES: return "Ammo: Missiles"; 
    case COMP_AUX_COUNTERMEASURES: return "Ammo: Countermeasures";
    case COMP_AUX_NANOBOTS: return "Extra: Nanobots"; 
    default: 
        throw std::exception("The provided AuxComponent does not have a textual description.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't like all the switches (I suppose you are doing it for speed (doubt it makes a difference)).

I would a couple of tests to see if using switches actually does make a significant difference, compared to virtual functions in terms of speed in your use case scenarios.

But it (switches) makes the code a mess and hard to compartmentalize (maintain/fix), I would use classes to encapsulate meaning and prevent bugs. It also makes bugs more likely.

Prefer to throw `std::runtime_error` rather than `std::exception`. It narrows down the type you need to catch at runtime. PS if you are really going for speed then exceptions can be more costly than virtual function calls (but measure).

I prefer putting const on the right (there is one corner case where it matters). But the community is still split over this so you take it or leave it:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Components<T>& c) 

I prefer:

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Components<T> const& c) 
                                                   //     ^^^^^^

// Its a const ref.
```

It also makes reading types easier. As you read types from right to left and const always binds to the left (unless it is the first item then in binds right).

```
// Components<T> const&
//                    ^  Reference to
//               ^^^^^   const
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^         Components<T>

   char const * const   data  = "Plop";
   char const * const&  data1 = data;
//                   ^      Reference to
//              ^^^^^       Const
//            ^             Pointer to
//      ^^^^^               Const
// ^^^^                     char
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason I use switches is that I think that in this case the code actually reads more easily this way than with a polymorphic approach; the combat system here is trivial, and to represent it with virtual methods would imho be an overkill. Good point about the `std::runtime_error`.

Comment: @electroLux: [Do polymorphism or conditionals promote better design?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/234458/14065)

Comment: I had to sleep on your advice, but in the end I took it and rewrote the code. For instance, Weapon is now an abstract class that is derived into LaserWeapon and MissileWeapon. The code does look better.